# Iterating a data-frame column: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) with a column called `Id` which looks like

```
        Id
 0       3
 1      67
 2     356
 3      
 :
50      P4
51      P5
52     678
53 
54       2
```

The column has a type: `dtype: object`
I have worked out the maximum Id value and assigned to a variable called maxId (which is 678 and am looking to apply a sequentially increasing maxId to the empty elements so in this example my output would be:

```
        Id
 0       3
 1      67
 2     356
 3     679
 :
50      P4
51      P5
52     678
53     680
54       2
```

Where element 3 and 53 are assigned values of 679 and 680 respectively.

I have tried the following code where i loop through the column looking for null elements and then applythuing the maxId to these:

```
for item, frame in df['Id'].iteritems():
        if pd.isnull(frame):
            maxId = maxId + 1
            frame['Id'] = maxId
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

What do I need to do for a fix?

Comment: In general with Pandas, you should look to avoid row-wise `for` loops. Vectorised column-wise operations are possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
# calculate maximum value
maxId = int(pd.to_numeric(df['Id'], errors='coerce').max())

# calculate Boolean series of nulls
nulls = df['Id'].isnull()

# assign range starting from one above maxId
df.loc[nulls, 'Id'] = np.arange(maxId + 1, maxId + 1 + nulls.sum())

print(df)

#      Id
# 0     3
# 1    67
# 2   356
# 3   679
# 50   P4
# 51   P5
# 52  678
# 53  680
# 54    2
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say you have already figured the maxId you can try this vectorized solution :

```
>>df

    Id
0   3
1   67
2   356
3   NaN
5   P4
6   P5
7   678
8   NaN
9   2

n = 678
n=n+1
df.loc[df.Id.isnull(), 'Id'] = list(np.arange(n,n+len(df.Id[df.Id.isna()].values)))
>>df
```

Output:

```
    Id
0   3
1   67
2   356
3   679
5   P4
6   P5
7   678
8   680
9   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the values like 'P4' and 'P5' ? I tried to reproduce a similar DataFrame to yours, but without those values and it just works :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [20,4, np.nan, np.nan, 12, np.nan, 6, 10]})

maxID = df['A'].max()

for i in range (len(df['A'])):
    if pd.isnull(df['A'].loc[i]):
        maxID +=1
        df['A'].loc[i] = maxID
```

I think your error occurs because you are trying to access an element of a float such as you would do with a list.

Exemple :

```
my_float = 3.0 
my_float[0]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```